# I am newbie in ruby on rails and trying to link into "changelog_settings.html.erb" page, but in the end, it redirect to different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

controller:

```
def add_changelog
        changlog_alert= params[:program][:changlog_alert]
        @program.update(changlog_alert: changlog_alert)
        flash[:notice] = "Changelog Updated Successfully."
        redirect_to portal_admins_changelog_settings_path(@enterprise, @program)
end
```

routes:

```
namespace :admins do
        get "changelog_settings"
        post "add_changelog"
end
```

changelog_settings.html.erb

```
<div class="large-12 small-12 columns settings_menu_content px-6 white_shadow p-5"> 
     <%= render partial: "portal/admins/dashboard_settings/changelog" %>
    </div>
```

_changelog.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @program, url: portal_admins_add_changelog_path(@enterprise, @program), method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :changelog_alert, value: @program.changelog_alert, rows: "3" %>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    <p id="limit" style="text-align: right;margin-top: -10px;color: gray;"> <%= @program.changelog_alert ? (300 - @program.changelog_alert.split(" ").count) : '300' %> Words Remaining </p>
    <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-blue" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Rake route

```
portal_admins_changelog_settings GET             /app/:enterprise_id/:program_id/admins
changelog_settings(.:format)                               portal/admins#changelog_settings {:subdomain=>"portal"}
```

So mainly this _changelog.html.erb file trying to show and seems like route also fine but everytime it goes to different page

Comment: So a file that begins with an underscore is a partial, not a page.  What file should the path `portal_admins_changelog_settings_path` be showing?

Comment: I have another HTML file called "_changelog.html,erb" that one I am trying to show if I am mistaken your question

Comment: There is something off here.  Do all your view files have an underscore at the beginning?  Are you following some kind of tutorial?  Can you post the output of running `rake routes` ?